# How can I get the index of a key/value pair in a Map?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following map

```
final CountryCodeToName =
  {
    "US": "01",
    "GBP": "17",
    "EUR": "33"
  };
```

With this map I can successfully retrieve the Currency name from the numeric value like this

```
CountryCodeToName.entries.firstWhere((element) => element.value=='33').key  // returns EUR
```

But is there anywhere to return the index of that value as well?  In the above example it would be `2` (3 is also fine)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think Maps store index values,  solution might be storing the key value pairs as a List

Answer (score 0):

you can make a list with your countries and convert it it into Map

```
   myList.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
    int idx = entry.key;
    String val = entry.value;

    return something;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of keys and another key of values, whichever you want and access the index of that list like you would normaly do

```
void main() {
  
  final myList =
  {
    "US": "01",
    "GBP": "17",
    "EUR": "33"
  };
  
  var values = myList.values.toList();
  var keys = myList.keys.toList();
  
  print(values[2]);
  print(keys[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CountryCodeToName.values.toList().indexWhere((element) => element=='33') // gives 2
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate list for this map's values list and then get the index of that particular value index from that list.

```
List<String> valueList= CountryCodeToName.values.toList();
int index= valueList.indexOf("33");
```